# How to set an environment variable in escript or Erlang

Tags: bash, erlang, environment-variables

Can I set an environment variable when executing an escript script so that the environment variable can be read by other applications executing in the same environment (so effectively is there an equivalent of bash command `export` available in escript or Erlang)?

Comment: A process cannot affect the environment of its parent or of its parent's other child processes. If you want to modify the environment for processes started by your script (via `fork` or something similar), there is probably something like `setenv` available.

Comment: Makes sense. Please put it as an answer and I will accept it if nothing else comes up. Erlang or escript code isn't capable of spawning new system processes (via `fork` or similar) because it itself executes in a VM (Erlang Virtual Machine). I was thinking that the OTP (Erlang libraries) may have a special system call to do that but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You can use [open_port/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2) to spawn processes.  Such processes will see any changes you've made to the environment with [os:putenv/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/os.html#putenv-2), as well as with the `env` option to `open_port`.

Comment: @legoscia can you please put it as an answer? It's not exactly what I've been looking for, but it is good for reference. It would be the right answer if not the restriction mentioned by chepner (i.e. as soon as the Erlang VM is terminated the environment variable set with os:putenv disappears).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A process cannot affect the environment of its parent or of its parent's other child processes.

If you want to modify the environment for processes started by your script (via fork or something similar, although OP informs me this is not supported), there is probably something like `setenv` available.

Comment: to clarify, am i right that altering the user's profile file ( .bash_profile for instance ) and add the environment variable and load it ( with source command) while the parent most OTP process is still in effect will not be visible to a new child process of the OTP process ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this yet with other Applications in the same erlang process, but at least within an application you can set an environment variable from within Erlang code with:

```erlang
os:putenv("EXAMPLE_VAR", "example_val").
```

Read it back with:

```erlang
os:getenv("EXAMPLE_VAR").
```

In Elixir you can use the same Erlang module:

```
:os.putenv('EXAMPLE_VAR', 'exmaple_val')
:os.getenv('EXAMPLE_VAR')
```

Or use the `System` module which has a more idiomatic Elixir interface:

```
System.put_env("EXAMPLE_VAR", "example_val")
System.get_env("EXAMPLE_VAR")
```